Precognitive badge not awarded?
I've just noticed that I didn't get the precognitive badge even though I started following the project before it entered the commitment phase. I'm in the list of recent followers on the right:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388?phase=definition
Any idea what could be the issue?

If you met the criteria, you should have been awarded the badge upon registration. But if it's any consolation, nobody has the badge here. So either something is wrong with SE, or nobody followed the proposal before it entered commitment phase (and registered) - which I find hard to believe.
According to the proposal page (see "commitment start" on the right), the proposal went into commitment on 2011-04-25. Are you sure you were following it before that?


Okay, it looks like I got confused. I just checked my profile and I've only been a member of Area 51 since August, so indeed I didn't follow the project before the commitment phase (don't know why I was convinced I saw the project going through the three phases).

Actually you're not in the list... Or at least, I can't find you. :)

I'm in the list on the right, the third from the bottom.

Do you remember by any chance about when the site entered the commit phase?

@景洛弘 Do you have a different nickname there? Because I really can't find you with this nick... No, I don't remember sorry.

Sorry, my nickname there is "Laurent".
